# How to get special string using RegExp?

Tags: regex

Here is the list of data.

```
file:///E:/in/aaaaaaa
file:///E:/in/bbacc
file:///E:/in/ddafc
...
```

I wish to get strings like aaaaaaa, bbacc, ddafc after "/in" word using RegExp.

Answer (score 1):

```js
file_path = 'file:///E:/in/aaaaaaa';
var str = file_path;
alert(str.replace('file:\/\/\/E:\/in\/', ''))
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript like this

```
var str = "one thing\\\'s for certain: power blackouts and surges can damage your equipment.";

alert(str.replace(/\\/g, ''))
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want to use JavaScript.

You can work on your regular expression using an online tool like [regex101](https://regex101.com/), it's handy because it will catch your syntax errors and also explain what each part of the regular expression is doing. I find it very useful.

Here's some JavaScript that illustrates how to match your strings and extract the part that you need

```
var pattern = /^.*in\/(\w+)$/; // create a regular expression pattern, note that we include a capturing group (\w+) for the part of the string we wish to extract
var regexp = new RegExp(pattern); // create a RegExp object from your pattern

var filePath = "file:///E:/in/aaaaaaa"; // this is the string we will try to match

if(regexp.test(filePath) == true) { // if the pattern matches the string
    var matches = regexp.exec(filePath); // call exec() to receive an object with the matches
    console.log(matches[1]); // matches[1] contains what the first capturing group extracted
}
```

I recommend playing around with regex a bit to understand them, they are quite complicated at first and it takes some practise. Here's another website you might find useful: http://www.regular-expressions.info/